# Can no longer set "annonymous" record fields

Tags: java, jooq

After updating Java and JOOQ a previously working function seems to run into a type casting error, specifically the lines record.set/with(or any version of setting a column) ...

```java
public void set_col_value(String col, String val, int options) {
        final boolean optional = (options & Optional_Value) != 0;
        if (val == null) {
            if (optional) {
                return;
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("missing value: " + val);
        }
        final boolean as_bool = (options & As_Boolean) != 0;
        if (as_bool) {
            if (val.equals("true")) {
                record.set(table.field(col), true);
            } else if (val.equals("false")) {
                record.with(table.field(col), false);
            } else {
                throw new RuntimeException("bad boolean value: " + val);
            }
        } else {
            record.with(table.field(col), val);
        }
    }
```

they give this error

```
    error: no suitable method found for set(Field<CAP#1>,boolean)
                    record.set(table.field(col), true);
    method Record.<T#1>set(Field<T#1>,T#1) is not applicable
      (inference variable T#1 has incompatible bounds
        equality constraints: CAP#2
        lower bounds: Boolean)
    method Record.<T#2,U>set(Field<T#2>,U,Converter<? extends T#2,? super U>) is not applicable
      (cannot infer type-variable(s) T#2,U
        (actual and formal argument lists differ in length))
  where T#1,T#2,U are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>set(Field<T#1>,T#1)
    T#2 extends Object declared in method <T#2,U>set(Field<T#2>,U,Converter<? extends T#2,? super U>)U extends Object declared in method <T#2,U>set(Field<T#2>,U,Converter<? extends T#2,? super U>)
  where CAP#1,CAP#2 are fresh type-variables:
    CAP#1 extends Object from capture of ?
    CAP#2 extends Object from capture of ?
```

Comment: Between what versions are you attempting to upgrade? Also, where's that `record` reference defined?

Comment: updating from java 8 to the latest java 17, so updated to the latest jooq 3.16, the record reference is being defined further up in the class containing this method, it's just a jooq Record object.

Comment: OK, but what version are you updating *from*, and can you please show the exact type specification? I'm assuming some raw types are involved, but I can't guess that...

Comment: I think the error is referring to the generic returned by `table.field(col)`  is not applicable for the set method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to answer why things used to work and no longer do, I'll need more info (see comments). You probably changed something else as well, including removed some raw type cast, etc.

But they aren't supposed to work. Look at the [`Record.set(Field<T>, T)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Record.html#set(org.jooq.Field,T)) and [`Fields.field(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/Fields.html#field(java.lang.String)) methods. The latter returns `Field<?>` with a wildcard. You can't just pass `Field<?>` and `boolean` to the `Record::set` method, the `T` types must match.

Here's are possible workarounds for that particular call:

```java
// Using raw types
record.set((Field) table.field(col), true);

// Using unsafe casts
record.set((Field<Boolean>) table.field(col), true);
```

I can't remember a jOOQ version where this wasn't required...

Comment: sorry 

Jooq 3.10.2 => jooq 3.16

Comment: there was no casting beforehand, what i posted above was the exact same as what i had before except it looks like changed one of the .with to .set while trying a bunch of things, the entire point of this method was to allow db updates without having to write seperate logic for every single table column.

Comment: Hey thanks i think the casting is working, funnilly enough the build error seems to have gone away simply by creating a field variable


`Field field = table.field(col);`


and replaceing all the 
`table.field(col)`
 with that variable. I'm assuming it's doing the same thing as the (Field) cast and turning Field<?> into just Field